# Problems calculating time difference Moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

```
function myFunction() {
    moment.locale('pt-BR');

    var intervalo = moment();
    var periodo = moment("2000", "hmm").format('LT');
    var atual = moment().format('LT');

    document.getElementById("atual").innerHTML = "Atual: " + atual;
    document.getElementById("periodo").innerHTML = "Periodo:" + periodo;

    intervalo=periodo.diff(atual).format('LT');
}
```

In the browser, it displays the message: ***periodo.diff is not a function
    at myFunction.***

I want to calculate the difference between the current time at a specified time, timing the remaining time

Answer (score 1):

The format method turns the moment object into a string. Try this:

```
function myFunction(){
  moment.locale('pt-BR'); 

  var periodo = moment("2000", "hmm");
  var atual = moment();
  var intervalo=periodo.diff(atual, 'years', true);

  document.getElementById("atual").innerHTML = "Atual: "+atual.format('LT');
  document.getElementById("periodo").innerHTML = "Periodo:"+periodo.format('LT');
  document.getElementById("intervalo").innerHTML = "Intervalo:"+intervalo;
```

Comment: Haha - you beat me by about 10 seconds :)

Comment: thanks, but the browser returned this: ` intervalo.format is not a function
    at myFunction ((index):19)`

Comment: I believe the calculation was done because throwing the variable in an alert and resulted in a number, but then it does not accept the .format

Comment: @Felipe Sorry, try it with the above edit. The diff function returns a number, not a moment object. Here we return the diff in years.

Comment: Thanks, but the result is not exactly a timetable.The result obtained: 9.679030833333334. I need a result like this: 9:57

Comment: @Felipe okay... Try `moment('0000', 'hmm').add(moment('2000', 'hmm').diff(moment())).format('H:mm')`